# Can a ninja learn a jutsu that lies outside of their own alignment?

Tags: naruto

Quite some time ago I got into a... minor argument regarding whether or not a ninja could in fact learn a jutsu to which their natural alignment was not geared toward. I felt you could, but it would be more difficult than it would be for someone whose natural alignment lies with that element. The person I was discussing it with did not. They felt it was impossible for a ninja to learn a jutsu outside of their natural alignment.

I stopped reading Naruto quite some time ago but I was wondering if anything came up that answered that question in one way or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not impossible, but it is rather difficult to do so. All Jounin level ninjas have to master more than two elements. Kakashi can perform 3 different element jutsu: Lightning, Fire, Earth. Yamato can do Earth and Water. Sasuke can do Lightning and Fire.

Even if someone has a natural inclination towards one element (Sasuke towards Fire), they can still perform other elemental jutsu (Sasuke can perform Chidori, a Lightning Release).

Comment: Kakashi, admittedly, cheats. He *does* have a sharingan at that point.

Comment: its valid for all other ninjas. all top class ninjas can use more than one element. many are there. the sannin, gokage, the jinchurikis, etc.

Comment: Kakashi does cheat with the sharingan, but factually, he has used all 5 main natures, just like the 3rd hokage. He has also used Genjutsu which in a way is a 6th

Comment: Sasuke's alignment is Thunder/Lightning. Kakashi gave him a paper to test his elemental alignment and the result was Thunder/Lightning, which he then commented that it was the same as him.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I do have to say that it is possible for ninjas of higher rank to master a jutsu that lies outside their own alignment.

For example:

1. **Sasuke** → Fire Release, Lightning Release.

   [image: Sasuke's Fire Release]

   [image: Sasuke's Chidori]
2. **Onoki (Third Tsuchikage)** → Dust Release, Earth Release, Wind Release, Fire Release

   [image: Onoki Jinton release]
3. **Sarutobi Asuma** → Wind Release, Fire Release.

   **He even got injured by his own attack while he was batting with Akatsuki members Hidan and Kakuzu**

   [image: Asuma Fire release]
4. **Kakuzu** → Earth Release, Wind Release, Lightning Release, Fire Release, Water Release (anime only).

   [image: Kakuzo]

I won't be considering Kakashi and Yamato for different reason, as Kakashi had Sharingan and Yamato was one of the guinea pigs of Orochimaru's experiment. But yes, since they are ninjas and based on your question, they do satisfy the condition:

**Kakashi** → Fire Release, Earth Release, Water Release, Lightning Release.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah it can be true according in naruto it is 29% because chakra heals our body. from the 7 chakras in the body. It maybe possible that you can perform jutsu but only God have powers, think about that we cannot fly like superman, We cannot float waters, We cannot fight with magic
and punch like superman that is 2 meters. What about jutsu did you think they are real? When I rotate my chakra and I perform hand seals and I say Shadow Clone Jutsu and in the next one Kage Bunshin no jutsu, but what? It didn't work, but you didn't have to say that, shadow clone jutsu , I tried that too but nothing happened I only reduced my strength and chakra, yeah I can perform but it's difficult to learn so difficult
Don't believe that in Japan ninjas it can perform jutsus that is only a myth. I can only perform jutsu to heal my body, it is not in sakura's healing jutsu. If you believe in jutsus you are addicted in anime with powers including: naruto,dragonball etc. Check this it might be helpful search:7 chakras in body. I know there's somethings you cannot understand because I am a Filipino. There are chakras in our body but cannot perform jutsus

Comment: add link to cite your reference perhaps?